# How can I select all ids of items bound to an observable using Async Pipe with a button click?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a table bound using Async Pipe, and have a button outside of the table which, when clicked, needs to fill an array of all the Id's of the items bound in the table.  Is the proper way to create a button an using rx.fromEvent(....) or to use the angular (change) event to inspect the observable?  If so, what recommended operators should I use to extract these id's without creating unnecessary subscriptions?

Comment: Could you provide a short sample table with a couple items and a button? Currently it's not very clear what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table observable is a hot observable

in your template ( not sure what's the attribute you map to or if you are using `*ngFor` hope you get the idea)

```
<table data="tableData | async">.... </table>
```

your button

```
<button (click)="fillId.next($event)">fill id</button>
```

in your component

```
fillId=new Subject()
    combineLatest(tableData,fillId).pipe(map(([data,evt])=> 
....do your id filling and return a record
)
))
```